# Execute a Data Flow Task based on a variable?

Tags: ssis

Just as a simple example: I only have two Data Flow Tasks (DT1 and DT2) in the my Control Flow. I have package configuration set up to populate a Variable based on a value in the SSISConfiguration table. How can execute DT1 if the variable is true and DT2 if variable is false. Do I need to add a dummy Control Flow tasks (script task) so I can use an expression in a precedence constraint? Or use the Disable property for the Task? What's the best way of doing this?

Thanks!

SSIS 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard on our team is to use a dummy script task with precedence constraints to choose which path to take.  I typically put this setup into a sequence container, and add a PostExecute event handler to log which path was actually taken.

I wouldn't bother with using the disable flag when I can directly control which task executes, but I can see doing that way.

I like the dummy script task approach because it can be upgraded to a real script if (when) the business logic gets enterprisey, and the constraints generally don't need modification.

Comment: I like this solution better than using the Disable property. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would use an Expression to set the Disable property on DT1 (if variable is false) and DT2 (if variable is true).

Answer (score 0):

Best Way is to use a Script Task to determine one DT as True and other as False.     Disabling a DT would not suffice your Issue

Comment: What do you mean it the DT would result in errors? I've already done this before.